# Looking for a Python based Machine Learning library to process Images

Tags: python, mapreduce, machine-learning

I am working on a Python based MapReduce project in which I want to process images to create a system based on the data collected after processing. My objective is to use Python/IronPython and process images within multiple aspects i.e. size, encoding, properties, metadata etc. I am looking for some ideas specially in the area of Machine Learning Algorithms   implementation to achieve my objective. 
Thanks.

**More Info added Later:**

I have created the following blog explaining a list of Python based Machine Learning Libraries as below:

http://cloudcelebrity.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/machine-learning-libraries-in-python/

Comment: I've had good luck with OpenCV 2.3's Python bindings.

Comment: http://mlpy.sourceforge.net/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to break your problem into two seperate parts:

1) Image Processing

2) Machine Learning

For task (1) you have the [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/PythonInterface) and you can even use the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) binary or its Python bidnings to break down your image into quantitative paramaters.

Next for task (2) you can try any of these to process the result from above

[Milk](http://packages.python.org/milk/)
[Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/)
[PyML](http://pyml.sourceforge.net/)
[MDP](http://mdp-toolkit.sourceforge.net/)
[Shogun](http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295025/valueerror-at-image-tensor-tensoractivation-5-softmax0-shape-4-dtyp/47300005?noredirect=1#comment81555441_47300005 any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For image processing/computer vision, there is also a family of libraries based on numpy: scipy.ndimage, [scikits-image](http://scikits-image.org/), [pymorph](http://luispedro.org/software/pymorph) (which is kind of slow, but has a lot of stuff), and my own [mahotas](http://luispedro.org/software/mahotas). They all use numpy arrays and are interoperable (you can use functions from all of them and mix&match).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47295025/valueerror-at-image-tensor-tensoractivation-5-softmax0-shape-4-dtyp/47300005?noredirect=1#comment81555441_47300005 any suggestions