# ValueError at /image/ Tensor Tensor("activation_5/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 4), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph

Tags: python, django, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I am building an image processing classifier and this code is an API to predict the image class of the image the whole code is running except this line (pred = model.predict_classes(test_image)) this API is made in Django framework and am using python 2.7

here is a point if I am running this code like normally ( without making an API) it's running perfectly

```
def classify_image(request):
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['test_image']:

    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    fs.save(request.FILES['test_image'].name, request.FILES['test_image'])


    test_image = cv2.imread('media/'+request.FILES['test_image'].name)

    if test_image is not None:
        test_image = cv2.resize(test_image, (128, 128))
        test_image = np.array(test_image)
        test_image = test_image.astype('float32')
        test_image /= 255
        print(test_image.shape)
    else:
        print('image didnt load')

    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
    print(test_image)
    print(test_image.shape)

    pred = model.predict_classes(test_image)
    print(pred)

return JsonResponse(pred, safe=False)
```

Comment: How do you define _model_? Maybe the comment of this issue of a similar problem can help you: [Tensorflow backend - bug](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2397#issuecomment-254919212)

Comment: there is no model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test_image and input of tensorflow model is not match.

```
# Your image shape is (, , 3)
test_image = cv2.imread('media/'+request.FILES['test_image'].name)

if test_image is not None:
    test_image = cv2.resize(test_image, (128, 128))
    test_image = np.array(test_image)
    test_image = test_image.astype('float32')
    test_image /= 255
    print(test_image.shape)
else:
    print('image didnt load')

# Your image shape is (, , 4)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis=0)
print(test_image)
print(test_image.shape)

pred = model.predict_classes(test_image)
```

The above is just assumption. If you want to debug, i guess you should print your image size and compare with first layout of your model definition. And check whe the size (width, height, depth) is match

Comment: when I am running this code instead of django like normaly it runs perfectly but in api gives this error i dont know why

Comment: Can you post all the logs of classify_image class .

Comment: I mean, api execution result (output of print commands). Bad english, sorry

Comment: ValueError at /image/ Tensor Tensor(“activation_5/Softmax:0”, shape=(?, 4), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph

after model.predict_classes

Comment: Hey, the problem is that your classifier can not connect well with your web (wsgi). Someone https://qiita.com/itisyuu/items/7c9d7ff43b3936704918 also have same problem as you. All in japanese, but the code is available. Hope it could help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47842931/valueerror-error-when-checking-target-expected-model-2-to-have-shape-none-25 any suggestions?